# VBA isString vs isNumeric

Tags: excel, vba

I am validating data that is in some textboxes in a VB userform in Excel.

The data can either be a number that is 6-digits long, a string that is at least 3 characters long, or a combination of string and digits.

To do this I wrote:

```
If Len(Trim(Me.TextBox1)) = 6 And IsNumeric(Trim(Me.TextBox1)) Then
  (do operation)
Elseif Len(Trim(Me.TextBox1)) > 2 and IsString(Trim(Me.TextBox1)) Then
  (do another operation)
Else
  (do third operation)
End if
```

I can make it work with `isNumeric`, but it seems VBA does not support `isString`.

Is there a clever work around to solve this issue?

Comment: It's not that *' VBA does not support isString'*, it's because IsString doesn't exist. Try application.istext(Trim(Me.TextBox1)).

Comment: how about vartype()?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can call the worksheet function

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.IsText
```

I would probably feel more comfortable walking the string though and testing with AscW and if expecting A-Za-z then look for values in the ranges 65-90 and 95-122.

You can definitely improve on the following. You can refer to the [ascii codes](https://theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/capital-letter-z-uppercase-ascii-code-90.html) to determine the acceptable values that constitute text for you. Note also that there are a ton of functions out there on the web for performing exactly this task.

```
 Public Sub test()
    Dim s As String, i As Long
    s = "pr81"
    For i = 1 To Len(s)                          ' 65-90 and 95-122.
        Select Case True
        Case (AscW(Mid$(s, i, 1)) >= 65 And AscW(Mid$(s, i, 1)) <= 90) Or _
             (AscW(Mid$(s, i, 1)) >= 95 And AscW(Mid$(s, i, 1)) <= 122)
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Values are not all in range A-Za-z"
            Exit For
        End Select
    Next i
End Sub
```

---

Thanks to @DirkReichel here is a much simplified test:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim s As String, i As Long
    s = "pr81"
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        If LCase(Mid$(s, i, 1)) = UCase(Mid$(s, i, 1)) Then
            MsgBox "Not all letters"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will recognise a value such as (pr81) as text. How would you distinguish pure text and combination of text and numbers?

Comment: See my comment underneath. You can refer to the [ascii codes](https://theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/capital-letter-z-uppercase-ascii-code-90.html) to determine the acceptable values that constitute text for you.

Comment: I see what you mean. So I should set up a For Loop to go through value and ensure it is within range. Correct?

Comment: Awesome. Just to be more accurate, will be looking for the following range: 65 - 90 and 95 - 122, correct?

Comment: https://theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/lowercase-letter-z-minuscule-ascii-code-122.html

Comment: Yes. Oops! Sorry.

Comment: `AscW` uses [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html)'s [UTF-16](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf16-1) code units, not ASCII. UTF-16 is native to VBA strings (and, Java, JavaScript, .NET, VB4,...)

Comment: @QHarr instead of the whole `case` block, `If LCase(Mid$(s, i, 1)) = UCase(Mid$(s, i, 1)) Then` for "not a letter" will also do it.... no need to remember the code-ranges (unless you want to check for something which isn't a letter)

Comment: @DirkReichel Thanks guys. This is not my strong suit. I would welcome further comments.

Comment: @TomBlodget Many thanks. How would you suggest please I edit the above to make it more useful and accurate? This is not my forte but if I do ASCW("A") I get 65 as per the ASCII tables not 0041 as per the link. I have switched ASCW for ASC: Is that sufficient to remedy the situation please?

Comment: `AscW` is the right function to use. Sorry I didn't explain well. 0041 (often written like U+0041, both hexadecimal) is the Unicode codepoint for 'A'. UTF-16 is the encoding used by VBA. UTF-16 encodes U+0041 into one code unit. Such code units are the elements of VBA strings. So, `ChrW(61) = ChrW(&H0041) = AscW("A")`  (`Asc` doesn't use ASCII, either, but that's another story.) [For decades, many have been led to believe they are writing code and saving files in ASCII when it is simply not true. This belief is so strong that evidence to the contrary is discounted .]

Comment: I meant `ChrW(61) = ChrW(&H0041) = "A"` and `61 = &H0041 = AscW("A")`

Comment: If you feel anything in the above would benefit from an edit please feel free to do so and you will have my thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I am using:

```
Public Function IsString(ByVal v As Variant) As Boolean
' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Returns TRUE when v is neither an object nor numeric.
' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Dim s As String
    On Error Resume Next
    s = v
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        If Not IsNumeric(v) Then IsString = True
    End If
End Function
```

A mixture of characters and numbers will be recognized as a string of course. Isn't this the shortest way to solve the problem?